Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the @material-tailwind_react.js?v=25ac0a9e:144
Hi I'm trying to use material tailwind components with my vite-react app.
I'm working in webstorm ide.
I followed all steps provided from tailwind installation as:

Installed tailwind

npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p


Configured my template paths.

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}


Added directives to my index.css file:

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

Then i moved to material-tailwind installation as provided:

npm i @material-tailwind/react

Changed previous template paths to:


const withMT = require("@material-tailwind/react/utils/withMT");

module.exports = withMT({
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
});

At this stage Webstorm was giving to me 2 errors:
ESLint: 'require' is not defined. (no-undef)
ESLint: 'module' is not defined. (no-undef)


Added themeprovider to main.jsx:

import {ThemeProvider} from "@material-tailwind/react";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <ThemeProvider>
            <App/>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
)


After trying to run:

import './App.css'
import {Button} from "@material-tailwind/react";

export default function App() {
  return <Button>Button</Button>;
}

I got plenty of errors in the console:
screenshot of errors
I'm new to React and had no idea what was going on with these errors. Glad if u could help!

Did you solved this issue?

downgrade to "@material-tailwind/react": "^2.0.5" helped
